# Redis cluster & auto-discovery

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

Although very vague, Redis documentation states that it has auto-discovery. In what consists that auto-discovery?

If I create a cluster of 6 nodes in host A, is it possible to simply start a server on another host B and get it auto discovered and added to the cluster, without having to manually point one host to the other? Or do I always need to do `cluster add-node` or something like that to add the node to the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be only in the enterprise version of Redis not in the OSS version.